# How to add syntax highlighting for javascript in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ide, syntax-highlighting

I set up the Visual Studio IDE with syntax highlighting using the **"Fonts and Colors"** menu. This seem to work for C#, C and C++. For example, with C# code:

[image]

The keywords are orange and the classes, structures, interfaces, and other objects are blue, as expected.

However, when I try to use the same system for JavaScript:

[image]

As you can see, the keywords are orange, but the class name is white and the punctuation is blue. I want that to be the other way around.

When I change the **"Plain text"** item from `default(white)` to `blue`, it works, but that makes everything blue except keywords.

It seems that JavaScript objects aren't treated as a customizable entity in the **"Fonts and Colors"** menu, they just fall into the category of **"Plain Text"**. Is it possible to do something about this?

I think that installing the official TypeScript language support VS Extension from Microsoft would fix this, but I don't need TypeScript.